# Find out how many rows updated in MongoDb collection

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, database-cursor

I want to insert some documents at once using the 'pymongo' python library.
I use `db_connection.collection.insert_many(data)`
Which perfectly works.
But I want to find out how many objects inserted and how many duplicates ignored.
Is there any property in cursor which contains such an information about the query?

Comment: Did you see that `insert_many()` returns a list of "inserted_ids"? https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.InsertManyResult

Comment: Actually I don't want 'inserted_ids' , inserted collection's count is enough for me

Comment: If you have the list of ids, you can count them via `len()` though right?

Comment: It actually might help